# Correct way to implement an accessible tooltip in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, accessibility, tooltip

I am working on improving the accessibility of our web app, and am currently looking at tooltips. I'm currently using the @floating-ui/react-dom-interactions package to replace our ageing version of tippy. The app in question is using React, but the question isn't really about React, just general html/js best practice.

Looking at the documentation online on how to make an accessible tooltip (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/tooltip_role) it seems that the correct method is to ensure that the tooltip content is set to role="tooltip", is in the DOM at all times only shown when the triggering element is hovered or focussed, and that you link the triggering element to the tooltip with the aria-describedby property

This makes sense to me. However, the way that our current tooltips work (with the old version of tippy.js) and the example for tooltips given by the floating-ui documentation (https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-tree-wmmffl?file=/src/Tooltip.tsx:0-1486) both work by only adding the tooltip content and the aria-describedby property when the triggering element is hovered or focussed.

I can't help but think that this would not really work, as for example when a screenreader reads out the page to user, it doesn't move the focus around, so when it comes to describe the triggering element, it does not have the aria-describedby (and even if it did, the content isn't in the DOM). This would mean the screen reading user doesn't know that the tooltip exists, unless they focus on the element for some reason, at which point the tooltip comes into existence (and I'm not sure how screen readers would handle that, but I suspect it's a not ideal UX).

I guess the core of the question is, am I missing something, or am I correct that for a tooltip to be fully accessible, it needs to exist in the DOM and be linked via the aria-describedby property. And if so, why are so many libraries and examples doing it wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand the situation pretty well.  While `aria-describedby` *could* be a dynamic property, that's not how it's typically used.  As you described, it should always exist and what it points to should exist (but can be hidden, although you might want to just [visually hide it](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) and not hide it from screen readers).

The [tooltip pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tooltip/) is still a work in progress in the authoring practice but you can look at [issue 127](https://github.com/w3c/aria-practices/issues/127) and [128](https://github.com/w3c/aria-practices/issues/128) in the W3C github for progress.

Also keep in mind [WCAG 1.4.13 Content on Hover or Focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#content-on-hover-or-focus).  When the tooltip displays, make sure the *mouse* user can move the mouse to the tooltip and the tooltip remains visible.  Oftentimes, the tooltip disappears if the mouse is moved away from the triggering element.  If that happens, then a screen magnifier user won't be able to pan the tooltip itself into the magnifier.